# Calling overridden method with out parameter from C# to python (with pythonnet)

Tags: python, c#, python.net

In C# I have defined an interface with a method with an `out` parameter.
I implemented this interface in python, an now I want to call this method from C#. (I am using pythonnet)

What I see is that a method **without** `out` parameter works fine, but a method **with** an `out` parameter throws an access violation.

I know that out parameters are handled differently in pythonnet: you return a tuple with first the return value and the second tuple item is the out parameter.

Is this not supported?

Using pythonnet 2.5.2 (latest) with python 3.8.3

My C# code:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string MyMethod_Out(string name, out int index);
    string MyMethod(string name);
}

public class MyServer
{
    public void CallMyMethod_Out(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C#.CallMyMethod_Out: before MyMethod_Out");
        int index = 1;
        myInterface.MyMethod_Out("myclient", out index);
        Console.WriteLine($"C#:CallMyMethod_Out: after MyMethod_Out: index:{index}");
    }
    
    public void CallMyMethod(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C#.CallMyMethod: before MyMethod");
        myInterface.MyMethod("myclient");
        Console.WriteLine($"C#:CallMyMethod: after MyMethod");
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C#.DoSomething");
    }
}
```

My Python code:

```
import clr
import sys

sys.path.append('some_dir')
clr.AddReference("ClassLibrary1")

from ClassLibrary1 import IMyInterface, MyServer

class MyInterfaceImpl(IMyInterface):
    __namespace__ = "ClassLibrary1"

    def MyMethod_Out(self, name, index):
        print("Python.MyInterfaceImpl.MyMethod_Out")
        other_index = 101
        return ('MyName', other_index)

    def MyMethod(self, name):
        print("Python.MyInterfaceImpl.MyMethod")
        return 'MyName'

print('\nCall regular C# function')
my_server = MyServer()
my_server.DoSomething()

my_interface_impl = MyInterfaceImpl()

print('\nCall without out param')
my_server.CallMyMethod(my_interface_impl)

print('\nCall with out param')
my_server.CallMyMethod_Out(my_interface_impl) # Access Violation 0xC0000005
```

Output:

```
Call regular C# function
C#.DoSomething

Call without out param
C#.CallMyMethod: before MyMethod
Python.MyInterfaceImpl.MyMethod
C#:CallMyMethod: after MyMethod

Call with out param
C#.CallMyMethod_Out: before MyMethod_Out
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I expected:

```
Call with out param
C#.CallMyMethod_Out: before MyMethod_Out
Python.MyInterfaceImpl.MyMethod_Out
C#:CallMyMethod_Out: after MyMethod_Out: index:101
```